# To remove the other characters after the domain name

Tags: wordpress, url, hyperlink

i want to remove this character after the domain name https://bolorims.com/?v=bf7410a9ee72 so it should be only https://bolorims.com/ in wordpress

I have try the to permalink but is not working

Answer (score 0):

The permalink doesn't work if you already select the "post name" under the "common settings" and save and i'ts doesn't work check the plugin or custom code you may need to disable it thats all i remember just ask question if you don't understand or it doesn't

Sorry my english is bad because its my 3th language

Comment: What is the custom code to use

Comment: Create a child theme and make a function call it anything you wan't with the $url args then pass it to the function remove_query_args pass the function this "v", $url add it to function.php then add the filter ```add_filter("the_permalink","the function name here") i hope it works i

Answer (score 0):

## Python program to remove all the

## characters other than alphabets

## Function to remove special characters

## and store it in another variable

```
def removeSpecialCharacter(s):
    t = ""
    for i in s:
        if(ord(i) in range(97,123) or ord(i) in range(65,91)):
            t+=i
    print(t)
s = "$Gee*k;s..fo, r'Ge^eks?"
removeSpecialCharacter(s)
```